# Articles: "In the Future" vs "In Prospect"

Tags: articles

Why is it that in English we say, "In the future," but we also say, "In prospect"? I know that we can say, "In the prospect of," but we can't say, "This will turn out well in the prospect." HOWEVER, we DO say, "This will turn out well in the future," but we don't say, "This will turn out well in future." I get that we always use the with future, but why don't we always use "the" with prospect? Any answers out there? I have some curious students and I can't figure this one out on my own.

Comment: Can you add some examples where "In the prospect" is used? This doesn't sound quite right to me.

Answer (score 1):

> In the future

is a general phrase referring to a time from now.

> In the prospect of **X**
>   With the prospect of **X**

is a more specific phrase focussing on *something* and also in the future.

> **With the prospect** of travelling to Mars, NASA is growing salad in space.
>   To prepare for travel to Mars **in the future**, NASA is growing salad in space.

Comment: I agree that in specific phrasing, we use both "in the future" and "in the prospect of". However, why don't we say, "I guess that would work in the prospect."

We say, "i guess that would work in the future." and we say, "I guess that would work in prospect." So why not "in the prospect"?

Comment: @ClaraFranks  Hmm, to me, when using prospect like that, the meaning flips from being "potential" (with the prospect of) to being "prospective client", so a common phrase might be "I guess that would work **with** the prospect" or (your usage) "I guess that would help with our prospects for success".  I think **with** needs to be used with **prospect**, not **in**. Maybe because **future** only has one meaning (some time from now), whereas **prospect** needs context for clarification.